# Ubuntu using llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits) as graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I just installed ubuntu on my computer and I'm having a lot of trouble getting the graphics to work. Only one display is detected, and it is shown as unknown and I'm not able to change resolution.

When I go to the about page in settings, the graphics are shown as llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits), which I'm pretty sure is wrong as I have an rx 6800. I've been using windows my entire life, but finally decided to give linux a go, but I just can't figure it out.

There is a lot of threads mentioning llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits), but I'm brand new to ubuntu (just installed it today) so I have almost no idea what anyone is talking about. I tried following what some people said, but I'm afraid that I will/ already have made it worse.

I would provide more info, but I have no idea what info I should provide. If anyone has any idea how to help, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Ubuntu are you running?
The RX 6800 is pretty new, I would not expect driver support in anything older than 21.04

Comment: That might be it. I tried the 20.04 LTS, as I thought that would be the safest option. Is there an easy way to update, or should I just restart from scratch?

Comment: Didn't find a way to edit my previous comment, so I'll just add another. 
I decided to just start from scratch and completely wipe the harddrive i used, as I messed with a lot of settings, and downloaded a lot of stuff to try and fix the issue. Sadly the download is very slow for some reason so I won't get to test it today. Is there any tutorials on how to properly install ubuntu (dual boot with windows (uefi bios)) you'd recommend, just so I don't screw anything up?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to add a comment, but this guide for dual booting seems pretty well written. It is written for your case where you’re starting with a wiped drive. https://opensource.com/article/18/5/dual-boot-linux

If you were to already have windows installed this guide would apply:
https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/.

I’d recommend 21.04 over 20.04, but I found this post that said the 6800 xt doesn’t work out of the box with 21.04. https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ndon2i/ubuntu_2104_and_radeon_6800_xt_black_screen_w/. If you have troubles with ubuntu 21.04 I’d recommend pop os which is very similar to ubuntu but seems to include out of the box support for the 6800 xt. https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2021/03/30/system76-updates-pop-os-with-full-support-for-radeon-rx-6000-series/

Comment: I installed 21.04, and everything seems to work perfectly out of the box! Thanks!